# Certificates needed for Tridion 2011 SP1 install?

Tags: tridion

I try to install Tridion on a default Windows 2003 server.  I receive this error message in the logs:

> Failed authenticode verification of payload: C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp{fcc62529-e5a9-4df2-aaa3-e5d13af5643a}\CdWindowsServices

Previously I received a Thawte certificate from Tridion that solved the problem.  However, this server is not a member of a real Certificate Authority, etc.

It fails immediately when installing.  Any ideas?

Thanks,
Robert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a KB article available for this issue:
http://tridion.kb.sdl.com/kb/?ArticleId=3993&source=Article&c=12&cid=19#tab:homeTab:crumb:7:artId:3993

Answer (score 4):

Solution:

Open MMC, Add Snapin, Certificates, Local Computer.

Third-Party Root Certificate Authority, Certificates, Import

Choose thawte_Primary_Root_CA.pem (request from Tridion Customer Support if you do not have it)

Install Tridion :)